# iOS: SDK for viewing photos of your own album

Tags: ios, objective-c, photo

I basically want the ability to check first within two specific dates if a user has taken any pictures on his phone. If so, if he clicks a button in my app the photo viewer (ideally exactly the same as used in the Photos app) should be opened and only these pictures/videos should be displayed. Then the user can look at them, share them, basically also the exact same functionality as the Photos app offers. But how can I do that? So far it seems I would have to code this completely from scratch, since I don't want the user to "pick" any picture but just look at them, share them etc. Or is there any SDK for this?

Comment: There's a bunch of pods, but making your own solution shouldn't be too hard. Here's sample code for general fetch and display; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums. You need to add a custom predicate for your specs. The Photos viewer can be done with a UIPageViewController. The bottom thumbnails is a UICollectionView. The share options should be provided by the system.

Comment: Thanks I've already ffound this but unfortunately they don't offer it as Objective -C :-/  But it sounds rather complicated since I want swiping left/right, zooming the pictures, maybe editing them. Just everything the Photos app offers...

Comment: I see. That's a good month of work you've got yourself there if you want to replicate it all. Especially the editing suite is very complicated. Have you considered just piggybacking on Photos by saving your time range images to a custom album and letting the user edit or share from there?

Comment: Good advice...hm then I just leave out the editing then it shouldn't be hopefully too complicated